# Noise Floor of ADC using PWELCH

Tags: matlab, signal-to-noise, spectrum, noisefloor, psd

While using MATLAB's Pwelch function, I am not able to match the noise floor of the "Modelled" ADC to (Delta)^2/6 {1 sided Spectrum}.

```
F_tone = 1e3;                       %Frequency of Tone
OSR = 64;
Fs = F_tone * OSR;                  %Sampling Frequency
time_step = 1/Fs;                   %Time between samples
total_number_of_cycles = 2^12;      %Total number of complete cycles to 
                                    %                      simulate for
FFT_number_of_cycles = 2^7;         %Number of cycles used in 1 FFT 
                                    %                      computation
Amplitude = 100;                     %Amplitude of the sine wave
Bits = 8;                                   
q = 2*Amplitude/2^Bits;             %Quantisation Interval q = 0.7812
NG = 0.375;                         %Noise Gain for Hanning Window
CG = 0.5;                           %Coherent Gain for Hanning Window
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
time_period = 1/F_tone;
t = 0:time_step:time_period * total_number_of_cycles;
y_noiseless = Amplitude*sin(2*pi*F_tone * t);
%%%%%%% Adding Noise
y = y_noiseless + (1.5*q)*(rand(size(y_noiseless))*2-1); %Adding 1.5LSB noise
y_quantised = floor(y/q) * q+q/2; %Quantising 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
N_fft = (OSR) * FFT_number_of_cycles;
Fmin = Fs/N_fft;
sn = (NG * Fmin) / (CG)^2;
[S,F] = pwelch(y,hanning(N_fft),N_fft/2,N_fft,Fs,'onesided');
S = S * sn;
semilogx(F,20*log10(S));
%[![This gives the following image][1]][1]

N_Floor = 10*log10( ((q^2)/6) * (1/max(F)) ) % = -54.9772 dB
```

The Signal strength in the plot is matching theoretical expectation.
Theory says it should be 20*log10(2*Amplitude^2/4) = 73.9794 dB, and I am getting 73.9798 as shown in the image.

The noise floor spread by theory should be -54.9772dB, but I am getting ~-75dB in the plot.

I am not sure of the following things.
1. Am I modelling the quantisation correctly?
2. Which of my noise floor numbers are wrong? Theory or Simulated?

[image: PWELCH obtained from MATLAB]

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is interested in the answer, I solved it the following way.

```
clc
clear all
close all


%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DECLARING VARIABLES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
F_tone = 3.5e3;                       %Frequency of Tone
OSR = 64;
Fs = F_tone * OSR;                  %Sampling Frequency
time_step = 1/Fs;                   %Time between samples
total_number_of_cycles = 2^15;      %Total number of complete cycles to 
                                    %                      simulate for
FFT_number_of_cycles = 2^9;         %Number of cycles used in 1 FFT 
                                    %                      computation
Vref = 2; 
Amplitude = Vref/2;                     %Amplitude of the sine wave
Amax = Vref/2;

Bits = 8;                                   
q = Vref/2^Bits;             %Quantisation Interval
NG = 0.375; %Hanning
CG = 0.5; %Hanning
%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CREATING (y,t) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
time_period = 1/F_tone;
t = 0:time_step:time_period * total_number_of_cycles;
y_noiseless = (Amplitude)*sin(2*pi*F_tone * t);
%%%%%%% Adding Uniform Noise of 4 LSB. That should reduce the 8bit ADC to a
%%%%%%% 6bit ADC. Otherwise, because my sampling frequency is a multiple of
%%%%%%% my Tone, the spectrum will skirt.
y_noise = y_noiseless + (2*q) * (rand(size(t))*2 - 1);
y = floor( y_noise/q )* q; %

%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FFT COMPUTATION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
N_fft = OSR * FFT_number_of_cycles;
Fmin = Fs/N_fft;
sn = (NG * Fmin) / (CG)^2;

[S,F] = pwelch(y-mean(y),hanning(N_fft),N_fft/2,N_fft,Fs,'onesided');
semilogx(F,20*log10(S*sn))

N_floor = 20*log10((4*q)^2/(6*Fs))
Plot_floor = 20*log10(median(S))
Plot_higher_by = 10^(((Plot_floor - N_floor)/20))

Theoretical_SNR = 1.76 + 6.02*(Bits-2) + 20*log10(Amplitude/Amax)

signal_indx = F_tone/Fmin+1;
Fundamental = (sum(S(signal_indx-20:signal_indx+20)));
Noise = (sum(S(2:signal_indx-21)) + sum(S(signal_indx+21:end)));
SNR = 10*log10(Fundamental/Noise)
```

The output of the code will be

> N_floor = -182.7740
>
> Plot_floor = -182.3479
>
> Plot_higher_by = 1.0503
>
> Theoretical_SNR = 37.8800
>
> SNR = 37.6677

It is important to remember that to read off the deterministic signal off of a pwelch psd, you need to scale it according to the window and Fbin.
But the psd of the noise should be read without any scaling.